# how to list a specific string or number in a file in Unix

Tags: unix

for Example if your file has following lines

```
1=10200|2=2343i|3=otit|5=89898|54=9546i96i|10=2459

1=10200|54=9546i96i|10=2459|2=2343i|3=otit|5=8

1=10200|5=IGY|14=897|459=122|132=1|54=9546i96i|10=2459

1=10200|2=2343i|5=0|54=9546i96i
```

The output should be

```
5=89898

5=8

5=IGY

5=0
```

Comment: using regexp, so any grep/awk/sed

Answer (score 1):

You could use `grep` with the `-o` flag to return only the regexp matches.

Assuming you have a `file.txt` that you want to parse:

```
cat file.txt | grep -o -E "(\||^)5=[^|]*" | grep -o "5=[^|]*"
```

This will match anything that starts with `5=` up until the first `|`.

By running this command on the input you provided I get:

```
5=89898
5=8
5=IGY
5=0
```

Cheers

Edit: as Walter A suggested, my previous solution did not cover all cases. 
I have added an extra parsing step: first, you get all strings that match `5=...` at the start of a line, or `|5=...`, and then you remove the `|`.

Comment: How about `15=12345`, you fill find `5=12345`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `(^|[|])` for matching start of field (start of line or `|`) and remember/match string until next `|` or end-of-line.

```
sed -nr 's/.*(^|[|])(5=[^|]*).*/\2/p' file
```